# What function does で have in the sentence 馬は動物である?

Tags: grammar, particles

I have a denshijisho, always giving me helpful expressions attached to a kanji/word etc. and this time it was

> 馬は動物である。
>   A horse is an animal.

in which I don't understand the function of the particle de.

Answer (score 0):

「で」　in this sentence is a part of 「である」. 「である」 means 「です」 in <s>respectful speech</s> or written speech.

Comment: In academic writing, yes. In "respectful speech", that can be quite terribly wrong advice.